# Why tempdb database memory size is greater then SQL server memory size (SQL SERVER 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, administrator

I am working on sql server 2012(Standard Edition).While Checking  memory Configuation i found that sql server memory size is around 130GB and temdb memory size is 160GB.All other system database and production database has less memory than total sql server memory.How tempdb memory size grown to over sql server total memory???

Comment: Because a query needed that much room for intermediate data. There is no relationship between the amount of memory SQL Server has and the size of tempdb (except, of course, that tempdb will likely get utilized less on a server with lots of memory available). I'm not sure why you'd assume there is one.

Comment: Outside of memory optimized tables (which I don't think existed in 2012), databases don't have a "memory size". They have a *file* size, as in space allocated on disk, but as Jeroen says, there's no reason to expect any particular relationship between server memory and disk space.

Comment: The confusion may stem from the assumption tempdb is somehow an in-memory database. It's not. All data in tempdb is committed to disk just like a regular database, and is cached in memory where possible just like a regular database.